# Diagonalisation of tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, diagonalization

Say I have two diagonalisable matrices $A$ and $B$, diagonalisable in different basis'.
\begin{equation}
A=\sum_ia_i|a_i\rangle\langle a_i|\qquad\text{and}\qquad B=\sum_ib_i|b_i\rangle\langle b_i|\;.
\end{equation}
Clearly both are diagonalisable. Therefore $A\otimes B$ and $B\otimes A$ are both diagonalisable. I know that in general the sum of two diagonalisable matrices is not diagonalisable, however I was wondering if because of the symmetry involved in this problem, the matrix:
\begin{equation}
A\otimes B+B\otimes A
\end{equation}

might be diagonalisable?

I think this might help. First note that the square root of a diagonal matrix is diagonal and the inverse of a diagonal matrix is diagonal. The product of two diagonal matrices is diagonal. Assuming nothing about $A\otimes B+B\otimes A$ we can multiply by $\sqrt{A}^{-1}\otimes\sqrt{A}^{-1}$ on both sides leaving
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I}\otimes\sqrt{A}^{-1}B\sqrt{A}^{-1}+\sqrt{A}^{-1}B\sqrt{A}^{-1}\otimes\mathcal{I}\;.
\end{equation}
$\sqrt{A}^{-1}B\sqrt{A}^{-1}$ must be diagonal as $\sqrt{A}^{-1}$ and $B$ are both diagonal. We can therefore say $C=\sqrt{A}^{-1}B\sqrt{A}^{-1}$, where $C$ is a diagonal matrix. Then $\mathcal{I}\otimes C\otimes\mathcal{I}$ must be diagonal. If $A\otimes B+B\otimes A$ is diagonal this must be true, however this can also be true if $A\otimes B+B\otimes A$ is not diagonal.

Comment: If I had to hand a CAS then I would try to see what happens with $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 &0\\0 &0 &1\\ 0&-2 &3\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 1 &0\\-2 &3 &0\\ 0&0 &2\end{pmatrix}$. Does $M=A\otimes B+B\otimes A$ satisfy  $M^2-3M+2=0$?